# if statement to check list items

Tags: python, if-statement

I have the following list and variable:

```
x = [1,2,17,4,5,7,11]
v = 18
```

and I want (in a single `if` statement) to search in the list to check if it contains an item that if we subtract "or any other operation" it from v variable will equal to one "as example".

For the above example, the `if` statement will yield True since we have the item 18 (18-17=1).

Can we do that in a single if statement (without using a separate loop) with python ?

Comment: no, I'm not looking for the existence of a value ..

Comment: Yes you are. You are looking for `v+1`.

Comment: `if v+1 in x:
    print x.index(v+1)` - this might be helpful.

Comment: "I have X and I *want* Y" is a work assignment, not a question. Work assignments are things you give your employees.

Comment: @MIBMinion First you say ‘*subtract it from v*’ then you use `18 - 17` as an example. Which one should be subtracted from which?

Comment: @Biffen, as example ,  any operation allowed .. the idea is to check the values in the if statement with a loop

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer to your question is already in comments, but assuming you tried to make your example more minimal to hide a more complicated question (one where the operation for which you substituted subtraction is not invertible), you can do this in Python with the `any` function and a list comprehension:

```
x = [1,2,18,4,5,7,11]
v = 17
if any([a - v == 1 for a in x]):
    print("Found it!")
```

Comment: I gave a different answer but this one is great. any/all built-ins are so underrated.

Comment: Thanx, that's what I want ..

Answer (score 3):

You can get a list of answers out with a list comprehension that uses `if` statement:

```
x = [1,2,18,4,5,7,11]
v = 17
answers = [i for i in x if i-v==1]
print(answers) # [18]
```